# How do I give a UIButton in Swift 4 multiple taps to print a different string back to the outputLabel? Goal is to create T9 Text

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having problems trying to get a UI button to have multiple taps I know it's not ideal but if someone could show me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction that would be great. Below is my current code where I'm trying to create a function called two pressed that responds based off how many times its tapped.

```
var resultOfLabel = ""

@IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(singleTap(gesture:)))
    UIButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)

    let tapGesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTap(gesture:)))
    tapGesture2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
   UIButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture2)

    let tapGesture3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tripleTap(gesture:)))
    tapGesture3.numberOfTapsRequired = 3
    UIButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture3)

    let tapGesture4 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(quadrupleTap(gesture:)))
    tapGesture4.numberOfTapsRequired = 4
    UIButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture4)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func twoPressed(sender: UIButton) {

   @objc func singleTap() {
        print(“2”)
    }

   @objc func doubleTap() {
        print(“a”)
    }

   @objc func tripleTap() {
        print(“b”)
    }

  @objc func quadrupleTap() {
        print(“c”)
    }

    resultOfLabel += "\(sender)"

    outputLabel.text = resultOfLabel

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in that except get these 4 functions out of the IBAction method

```
let tapGesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.singleTap(_:)))
UIButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)
```

//

```
@objc func singleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    print(“2”)
   self.twoPressed(sender.View as! UIButton)
}

@objc func doubleTap() {
    print(“a”)
}

@objc func tripleTap() {
    print(“b”)
}

@objc func quadrupleTap() {
    print(“c”)
}


 @IBAction func twoPressed(sender: UIButton) {

  resultOfLabel += "\(sender)"
  outputLabel.text = resultOfLabel

 }
```

Comment: If I get the 4 functions out of the IBAction method how can I allow the IBAction to know what string to call when pressed?

Comment: what you're trying to accomplish ??? what type of action twoPressed IBAction is for ?

Comment: I'm trying to get a UI Button to print "2" if pressed once, print "a" if pressed twice, print "b" if pressed three times, and print "c" if pressed 4 times

Comment: I not sure if your familiar with old T9 text buts that what I'm trying to do